# Is it called a rope?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

When I hear "rope" I picture it as something like this
[image]

**Do we call this a rope or a string?**

[image]

Comment: Is it the colour, the material, or the thickness that makes you ask? This is not a very clear question.

Comment: And is it stretchy or not stretchy? If it's stretchy, it's not a rope, it's a **bungee cord**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How thick is it? That's the only difference.  If it is only a 1mm in diameter it would be string. If it is 10mm it would be rope.  There might be a grey area somewhere between.

To quote the late Spike Milligan:

> String
> is a very important thing.
> Rope is thicker,
> But string,
> Is quicker.
> PS. The meaning of this is obscure
> That’s why, the higher the fewer.